# Paginated survey (Vue.js, BootstrapVue) doesn't get selected items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I created a paginated survey with Vue.js, but it needs fixing.
I'm using radio button group from bootstrap vue.
For some reason, nothing is pushed into my selected array when some answer is selected like it is supposed to with bootstrap radio buttons.

- I doesn't matter which answer you choose, it's always the last button that gets checked.
  Can someone help me fix it?
  Here is a codepen:
  https://codepen.io/Yulya_Yu/pen/JjXMPxd

My code is below:

```
<template>
  <div type="survey">
    <div class="survey-container">
      <div class="radio-vote">
        <div class="survey-question-container" >
          <div class="survey-question-info">
            <!-- <p>{{ question.name }}</p> -->
            <p>{{ currPage + 1 }} из {{ subList.length }}</p>
          </div>
          <div v-for="question in filteredAnswers" :key="question.id">
            {{question.name}}
            <b-form-radio-group
              :options="question.answers"
              v-model="selected"
              stacked
              class="transition--fadeInRight"
              :disabled="selected.length === subList.length && selected.indexOf(n) === -1"
            >{{selected}}</b-form-radio-group>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-controls" v-if="!surveyFinished">
          <div class="pagination-btns">
            <button class="backwards" @click="onClickPreviousPage" :disabled="leftBtnDisabled">
            </button>
            <button class="forward" @click="onClickNextPage" :disabled="rightBtnDisabled">
            </button>
          </div>
          <button class="survey-finish-btn" @click="finishSurvey" :disabled="disableBtn">
            Завершить опрос
          </button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="surveyFinished" class="survey-finish-msg">
          <h3>Спасибо!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  mixins: [],
  props: ['questions'],
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
perPage: 1,
currPage:0,
leftBtnDisabled: false,
rightBtnDisabled: false,
subList: [],
surveyFinished: false,
selected: [],
disableBtn: false,
questionAnswers: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.setAnswerPages()
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
    setAnswerPages() {
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(this.questions.length / this.perPage); i++) {
        this.subList[i] = this.questions.slice(
          i * this.perPage,
          i * this.perPage + this.perPage
        )
      }
      this.leftBtnDisabled = this.currPage === 0
    },

    onClickPreviousPage() {
      if (this.currPage > 0) {
        this.currPage--
      }
    },

    onClickNextPage() {
      if (this.currPage < this.subList.length - 1) {
        this.currPage++
      }
    },

    finishSurvey() {
      this.surveyFinished = true
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredAnswers() {
      return this.subList[this.currPage]
    }
  },
  watch: {

    currPage() {
      if (this.currPage === this.subList.length - 1) {
        this.rightBtnDisabled = true
      } else if (this.currPage < this.subList.length - 1) {
        this.rightBtnDisabled = false
      }
      this.leftBtnDisabled = this.currPage === 0
    },

    selected() {
      if (this.selected.length === this.subList.length) {
        this.disableBtn = false
      }
    }
  },
  validations: {}
}
</script>
```

questions props looks like this:

```
      questions: [
        {
          name: 'test question 1 ????',
          answers: [
            {
              text: 'option 1',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 2',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 3',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 4',
              id: 1
            }
          ]
        },
                {
          name: 'test question 2 ????',
          answers: [
            {
              text: 'option 1',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 2',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 3',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 4',
              id: 1
            }
          ]
        },
                {
          name: 'test question 3 ????',
          answers: [
            {
              text: 'option 1',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 2',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 3',
              id: 1
            },
                        {
              text: 'option 4',
              id: 1
            }
          ]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure here - can you make working JSFiddle? But it looks like problem with v-model. You are using single `selected` property for all the questions. You should not probably use v-model in v-for, instead use some custom logic :value and @onchange. But it is a guess.

Comment: Hi!
I added codepen example, hope it will do https://codepen.io/Yulya_Yu/pen/JjXMPxd